# Google Cloud SQL database increase

Tags: sql, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

My Google Cloud SQL automatic storage increased up to 31GB but still the database size is only 120Mb and all the above happens in 3 days?

Answer (score 2):

If you have binary logging enable you will see an increase in the storage size because [Binary logs use storage space (not backup space), and are charged as storage](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq?hl=en_US&_ga=2.30134079.-128464051.1549905691#backup-and-recovery).

To find if you have binary logging enabled, on your instance details view, in the Configuration section, click Edit configuration > Enable auto backups (dropdown) and you will see if Enable binary logging is checked.

Comment: Good morning Ryan, thank you for your answer, I've checked the dropdown menu and the "binary logging" is not enable. I've fix this issue by creating a new database and it's working fine. I believe the increase comes by a wordpress photo optimize plug-in.

Comment: Glad that you found a solution to this